# Creating a menustrip in WinAPI?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, menu, menustrip

Is there a way to get a menustrip instead of an HMENU when using the WinAPI? Like menus that .Net applications use? Because the HMENU just doesn't fit my color scheme, I need a darker menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like the system defaults, you can owner-draw the menu.  If you only need to support Windows Vista and higher, you can follow this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756947.aspx).  Otherwise you need to call [ModifyMenu()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647993(VS.85).aspx) on your menu items and set MF_OWNERDRAW and everything that comes with that.